# How to find the shortest path cost?

Tags: c#, combinations, shortest-path

I have Two Arrays

```
string[] city = {"A","B","C","D"}
```

And the cost of connecting them say

```
int[] cost ={ 2,1,3,2,4,3}
```

The task is to find the shortest path cost which will be 6 here.

Why?

```
A->B = 2
A->C = 1
A->D = 3
--------- = 6 (cheapest)

B->C = 2
B->D = 4
B->A = 2
-------- = 8

C->D = 3
C->A = 1
C->B = 2
------------ = 6 (cheapest)

D->A =3
D->B = 4
D->C = 3
------------- = 10
```

and so on..total 16(2^4) such combination will appear.

I am refereing some questions in SO + others but not able to understand.

How to do it without taking help of any third partry library?And please provide an easy way of doing so!!

My attempt(not very correct)

```
public static int minimum_cost(string[] input1, int[] input2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int len = input2.Length;
    var storage = new int[input1.Length * input2.Length];

    for (i = 0; i < len - 2; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < len - 1; j++)
        {
            for (k = j + 1; k < len; k++)
            {
                var m1 = input2[i];
                var m2 = input2[j];
                var m3 = input2[k];

                storage.SetValue(m1 + m2 + m3, counter);                     
                counter++;
            }                   
        }              
    }
    return storage.Take(counter).Min();
}
```

**Invocation**

```
var input1 = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
var input2 = new int[] { 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3 };
var res = minimum_cost(input1, input2);
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense without context.  For example, which connections do your 6 integer costs represent?  Am I right to understand that your target is a graph in which all nodes are connected?

Comment: Your sample output doesn't show the shortest path but the most central city. A shortest path would travel sequentially through all cities, so not `A->B, A->C, A->D` but `A->B, B->C, C->D` etc.

Comment: @ Dan Puzey, yes sir...you can assume that they are connected in graph...

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter, here by cost I mean the weights

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal's_algorithm

Comment: There is no algorithm in the world that will give you the exact solution EVERY TIME except brute force calculation. All other approaches are aproximations and will give you something that is close to the best possible solution.

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter, have added an image.hope this will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a mapping between `city` and `cost`, so we can easily access the cost of each edge:

```
string[] city = {"A","B","C","D"};
int[] cost = {2,1,3,2,4,3};

var mappings = new List<Tuple<string, string, int>>();

var cs = new Queue<string>(city);
var e = cost.GetEnumerator();
while(cs.Any())
{
    var c = cs.Dequeue();
    foreach (var o in cs)
    {
        e.MoveNext();
        mappings.Add(Tuple.Create(c, o, (int)e.Current));
    }
}
```

`mappings` now looks like

[image]

Now that we have an appropriate data structure, finding the path costs is trivial:

```
var result = from c in city
             select new { c, cost = mappings.Where(m => m.Item1 == c || m.Item2 == c).Sum(m => m.Item3) };
```

[image]

```
var shortest = result.Min(a => a.cost); // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine your nodes something like this

```
    A   B   C   D
A   -   2   1   3
B   2   -   2   4
C   1   2   -   3
D   3   4   3   -
```

And then traverse this 2d array to run through all combinations. Saving data in 2d array might simplify the way you need to know costs.

And when you say

```
A->B = 2
A->C = 1
A->D = 3
--------- = 6 (cheapest)
```

It is actually you are starting at A, going to B, then C and finally ending up on D.

[Totally blank now, could have given you some sample code to run through it. Forgive me for that]

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the commet above the only way to be able to know the EXACT value is by going through all combinations.

In university on Graph Theory I did something like this

```
   A   B   C   D
A  -   2   3   1

B  2   -   2   4

C  3   2   -   3   

D  1   4   3   -
```

Now you just have to compute all possibilities
I like to do it like this

```
[A B C D]
[A B D C]
[A C B D]
...
```

You assign each solution the correct weight and pick the one which is shortest.